# Which format to use for the CN & DNS fields in a SSL certificate for an IDN?

Tags: ssl, idn

If I am issued a SSL certificate for an IDN domain, should I expect the value in the CN field to be the literal UTF-8 string for the domain name, or the escaped, punycode version?

What about the X509v3 Subject Alternative Name DNS entries, would those be in the same format?

Could I see some example crt files, or link to IDNs that are using SSL?

Is there a normative spec on this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about HTTPS, the rules traditionally used for host name verification are defined in [RFC 2818, Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1), which doesn't mention Internationalized Domain Names at all.

More recently, a "best practice" RFC, RFC 6125, was written to harmonise the host name verification procedures across protocols and clarify a number of other points. Here is what it says about IDN ([section 6.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.2)):

> ```
>  If the DNS domain name portion of a reference identifier is an
>  internationalized domain name, then an implementation MUST convert
>  any U-labels [IDNA-DEFS] in the domain name to A-labels before
>  checking the domain name.  In accordance with [IDNA-PROTO], A-labels
>  MUST be compared as case-insensitive ASCII.  Each label MUST match in
>  order for the domain names to be considered to match, except as
>  supplemented by the rule about checking of wildcard labels
>  (Section 6.4.3; but see also Section 7.2 regarding wildcards in
>  internationalized domain names).
> ```

Unfortunately, this may not help you in practice. Firstly, RFC 6125 is relatively recent, and few applications or libraries claim to implement it as far as I know. Secondly, not all libraries follow RFC 2818 to the letter anyway (browsers can sometimes be more tolerant regarding which CNs are acceptable, for example).

Comment: Any news on this since May 30 2012? I need a SSL cert for an IDN domain and am wondering if I should enter the UTF-8 name or the punycode name in CN etc in the cert request.